# When making an API call to omniture (site catalyst) , is there any way to use rolling dates

Tags: adobe-analytics, klipfolio

i have created a dashboard in klipfolio  and only need 52 weeks data to be fetched by the api with respect to current date .. currenlty i m manualy passing date but i want it to use the system date to automaticall fetch data for me

"dateFrom": "2018-01-10",
    "dateTo": "2018-02-05",

Comment: depending on the exact report request, the api does support relative date values https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/r-reportdescription-1#reference_9ECD594AEDD240D7A475868824079F06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Klipfolio's date parameters](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/216181877-Date-parameters-in-data-source-queries) to accomplish this. In your example, you want the last 52 weeks from today so your query for dates could look like this:

```
"dateFrom": "{date.addWeeks(-52).format()}", "dateTo": "{date.today}",
```

Alternatively, if you want it to start on first day of the week 52 weeks ago, your query for dates could look like this:

```
"dateFrom": "{date.addWeeks(-52).startOfWeek.format()}", "dateTo": "{date.today}",
```

This will create a 52 week rolling window relative to today so you will not have to update your query every week.

Comment: Thanks, buddy helped a lot!